# Is there a way to ONLY add tables to an edmx file?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, edmx

I wanted to ask if there is a way to ONLY add new tables to the edmx file without updating (refreshing) or deleting the existing table?

Answer (score -2):

Sure, If you right click on your EDMX model diagram. You can select update model from database. A dialogue box will pup up. The dialogue box has tabs up at the top one of them is add. From there expand the table menu and select the tables you want to add.

**Update 11/08/2014**

In this example Deleted table no longer exists in the Database. Open up your EDMX file. Right click in the white space around your tables and select Update Model from Database.
[image]

A dialogue box will pop up. Under the add tab expand tables and select only the tables you want to add. and click finish.
[image]

And you're done. Both tables still exist in your EDMX file.
[image]

Comment: That's true but this would also update and delete any tables not in the DB, so I wanted to ask if there is a way to add only without refreshing (Updating) or deleting

Comment: I just updated my answer with pictures to show that this is possible and how to do it. Hopefully that helps you out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts Brandon, but the problem is that if you did change anything in the old tables in the edmx, you will be forced to update them, as you'll find the tables that will be updated in the "refresh" tab, in which you can't check or uncheck the tables you need or do not need to update